# Assigning numbers to items in a loop -- SAS

Tags: sql, sas

Each ID number has several items associated with it. For every item under each ID, I want to assign a number to it. I would like the number to start at 1 for each ID. How would I do this in SAS? I'm guessing I can use a type of loop statement. Below is an example of my goal. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I have to add another layer to this problem. If the ID has item = SPECIAL, I want that record to always be assigned 1 and have the other items follow it.

```
+----+----------+----------+
|ID  |Item      |Assignment|
+----+----------+----------+
|A001|SPECIAL   |1         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A001|Orange    |2         |
+----+----------+----------+  
|A001|Pineapple |3         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A002|Banana    |1         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A002|Strawberry|2         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A002|Pear      |3         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A002|Watermelon|4         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A003|SPECIAL   |1         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A003|Banana    |2         |
+----+----------+----------+
|A003|Apple     |3         |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it - with BY statement and automatic variables FIRST and LAST. Original dataset should be sorted by ID before.

```
data have;
    input ID $ Item $;

    datalines;
A001 SPECIAL
A001 Orange
A001 Pineapple
A002 Banana
A002 Strawberry
A002 Pear
A002 Watermelon 
A003 SPECIAL   
A003 Banana
A003 Apple
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by ID;
    if FIRST.ID then Assignment=1;
    else Assignment+1;
run;
```

Regarding your additional layer: just add one more condition to the IF-statement:

```
 `if FIRST.ID or item='SPECIAL' then Assignment=1;`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It almost works, but any number after 1 is missing. Do you know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Works well for me. I'll add to my answer code for generating sample source data. IS it possible that in your real data there is already variable 'Assignment' and it's character?